# How to prove that cosine squared is a positive-definite function?

Tags: probability, fourier-analysis

I need some help with proving that function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb C$, $f(t)=(\cos(t))^2$ is a positive-definite function.

I know that if  $\sum_{k,l\le n}(f(t_k-t_l)z_k\overline  z_l)\ge0$ then $f$ is positive-definite, but I don't know how to show this inequality for my function. Does someone know any easier way to prove it?

Comment: Can you explain what are the $t_k$, what is $n$ and what are $z_k$?

Comment: This formula has to be true for all sequences of real numbers $t_1,...,t_n$, for all sequences of complex numbers $z_1,...,z_n$ and for all positive $n$.

Comment: To me it seems that $f$ is positive because you define $t$ to be a real number, therefore $cos(t)^2$ is non negative. On the other hand, in general $z_k \overline z_l$ is a complex number - am I missing something?

Comment: @astabada You are missing the distinction between "positive" and "positive definite".

Answer (score 4):

For every $a\in\mathbb R$, the complex exponential function $e^{iat}$ is positive-definite because
$$
\sum_{k,l} e^{ia(t_k-t_l)}z_k\bar z_l  = \left|\sum_{k} e^{iat_k} z_k\right|^2 \ge 0
$$
And $\cos^2 t$ can be written as a combination of complex exponentials with positive coefficients: 
$$
\cos^2 t = \frac12+\frac12 \cos 2t = \frac12+\frac14e^{2it}+\frac14e^{-2it}
$$

The above is a special case of the fact that the Fourier transform of a positive measure is a [positive-definite function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function); the converse is also true (Bochner's theorem).